# How to fixed my tab order that are in decimal 2.2 , 4.1 to integer like 2,3,4,5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I want to set my **tab order** form 1 to 50 in integer  but my tab are showing in decimal like

> 2.1, 1.2,4,5

How can I fix it?

[image: see the image]

Comment: I don't think you can. Tab order 2.0 just means it is the first tab position in the container with tab order 2. If you added another container inside the panel the controls in that container would start with tab order 2.x.x

Comment: Why? Is there a reason you want to flatten then tab order hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here. The tab order isn't a just a sequence of numbers like `1,2,3,4..` but a hierarchical ordering, separated by groups. For the first group, the tab order is `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..`. For the second group `2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ...`

If fact, the groups might have groups inside them, causing more hierarchical numbers, like `1.5.3`, or `2.1.4`.

Notice how the produce details group, has the number `2` next to it, and all the UI elements inside of it are `2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ..`

Comment: Yes but I don't want to create a groups i want to be like integers. how can I revert the groups?

Comment: The groups get created automatically based on how you arrange the UI. Put items in a container (like a group box, or a panel) and you have a new group.